# How to export a OneNote template?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, templates

I have built a OneNote template that I wish to share with colleagues? Is there a similar mechanism to the word .dotx files that I can use to save and share the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean a Page Template or a templated notebook?

Page Templates cannot be saved separately as such. They exist in a special OneNote file at:

```
 %appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\My Templates.one
```

A notebook can easily be copied as it is a folder/file collection. Simply find the location on your drive. Options\Save & Backup shows you where the files are. You can also export the notebook to a package file.

Comment: Page template. Ah, I thought that might be the case. At the moment I am distributing it as an exported workbook so people can add it to their page templates.

Answer (score 0):

As [Julian](https://superuser.com/a/894267/542598) said, page templates exist as a special OneNote notebook stored in

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\
```

The notebook is called `My Templates.one` (or translated, e.g. `Meine Vorlagen.one` in German).

However, at least now, you can share your templates by copying the notebook and renaming it, e.g. to `My Shared Templates.one`. If you then give it to your colleagues and ask them to copy it to the specified folder, it will appear as an additional template category with the given file name in OneNote:

[image]